# Why did Jon Snow refuse to escape with Daenerys when he had the chance

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the 6th episode of Game of thrones season 7, when Daenerys arrived to save Jon Snow and others, Daenerys offered escape on a dragon, but Jon refused and continued fighting against the army of dead while he could have easily climbed the dragon and left.

Why did he not escape when he had the chance?

Comment: The title of this question seems oddly specific to me. Based on the body, I would assume your question is more about why he didn't flee with Daenerys there and then. Consider editing the title if this is true.

Comment: It's a bit like asking why someone took a step, instead of asking why he went somewhere.

Comment: @JAD yes, why Jon snow didn't flee there and then

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For two reasons...

**Firstly**

He's actually about to take Dany's hand but sees that the party is still being attacked at close quarters.

He turns and defends the other member of the party so that they have time to climb on the dragon and, *importantly*, **complete the mission** by taking the wight with them.

Then things get away from him..

**Secondly**

Once he's involved with defending the party he goes into a kind of berserker mode.. defending the party but just despatching the dead without really giving thought to the consequences.

He's moving further and further away from the party... and towards the Night King...his principal enemy. You can see the expression on his face is one of defiance and anger.

[image]

Only when the Night King threatens to take down the dragon Dany is riding does he come to his senses.

Now the party is *really* at risk of not escaping and, thus, failing in their mission...so he tells them to go but is taken down and pushed under the ice as he attempts to re-join the party.